Using iconv to convert from IBM-500 to some form of UTF
This question is specifically about AIX where the option to use WCHAR_T isn't available.
I was under the impression that UTF-32BE was an example of a UTF codepage that everything could be converted from/to.
When I try to use iconv thus, it complains that it cannot open converter.
iconv -f IBM-500 -t UTF-32BE

I do have problems figuring out what the correct 'names' are for the codepages but I am certain the IBM-500 and UTF-32BE are both correct because the following two invocations of iconv are successful.
iconv -f IBM-500 -t IBM-850

iconv -f IBM-850 -t UTF-32BE

So I guess I have two questions.

Why can't iconv convert from EBCDIC code page 500 to UTF-32?
What is a "universal" code page I could use instead of UTF-32BE that would be able to convert from/to everything?

